# Classifications of Marks by Grades

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I have data of a Subject Marks in a column of **marks.csv** file as given below.

```
    Students Marks
0   Santosh 90
1   Mahesh  35
2   Suresh  15
3   Ganesh  45
4   Ramesh  60
5   Supriya 25
6   Ritesh  50
7   Pooja   95
```

I want to classify this marks as per grades:

```
Marks > 80 (Distinguished);
Marks > = 50 & Marks < 80 (First Class);
Marks > = 35 & Marks < 50 (Second Class);
Marks  < 35 (Failed).
```

In result, I need output in same file **.csv** as like given below.

```
    Student Marks Grades
0   Santosh 90  Distinction
1   Mahesh  35  Secnd Class
2   Suresh  15  Failed
3   Ganesh  45  Secnd Class
4   Ramesh  60  First Class
5   Supriya 25  Failed
6   Ritesh  50  First Class
7   Pooja   95  Distinction
```

Any suggestions is helpful.

Comment: have a look at this
https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d

Comment: Great! This is a straightforward thing to do with pure Python and the `csv` module. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm just beginner in Python. I have tried                                                                   if(avg>=80):
    print("Distinction")
elif(avg>=50&avg<80):
    print("First Class")
elif(avg>=35&avg<50):
    print("Second Class")
else:
    print("Failed")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function

**Code**

```
def add_grades(filenm):
    ''' Add Grades column to CSV file '''

    def mark_to_score(marks):
        " Converts a mark to a grade "
        if marks > 80:
          return "Distinguished"
        elif 50 <= marks < 80:
          return "First Class"
        elif 35 <= marks < 50:
          return "Second Class"
        else:
          return "Failed"

    # Read CSV file into pandas dataframe
    #   CSV file is space delimited
    df = pd.read_csv(filenm, delimiter=r"\s+")

    # Create Grades column
    df['Grades'] = df['Marks'].apply(mark_to_score)

    # Apply to function to Marks column to obtain grades
    df['Grades'] = df['Marks'].apply(mark_to_score)

    # Write output back to CSV (space delimited)
    df.to_csv(filenm, sep=' ')
```

**Usage**

add_grade('Name of CSV File.txt')

**Test**

Input file ('grades.txt'):

```
   Students Marks
0   Santosh 90
1   Mahesh  35
2   Suresh  15
3   Ganesh  45
4   Ramesh  60
5   Supriya 25
6   Ritesh  50
7   Pooja   95
```

Output file ('grades.txt')

```
 Students Marks Grades
0 Santosh 90 Distinguished
1 Mahesh 35 "Second Class"
2 Suresh 15 Failed
3 Ganesh 45 "Second Class"
4 Ramesh 60 "First Class"
5 Supriya 25 Failed
6 Ritesh 50 "First Class"
7 Pooja 95 Distinguished
```

Note: multiple words in grades column (e.g. "First Class") are in quotes otherwise space in word would be mistaken for a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes in earlier code. Here, you can save the **Grades** column without any error.

```
import pandas as pd
    filenm = 'marks.csv'
    
    def mark_to_score(marks):
            " Converts a mark to a grade "
            if marks > 80:
              return "Distinguished"
            elif 50 <= marks < 80:
              return "First Class"
            elif 35 <= marks < 50:
              return "Second Class"
            else:
              return "Failed"
    df = pd.read_csv(filenm)
    df['Grades'] = df['Marks'].apply(mark_to_score)
    df.to.csv(filenm, sep='\t')
```